# Complex measures, Total variation.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Rudin book's, Real and complex analysis chapter 6.

[image]

Of (1) every rearrangement of series must also converge.

My questiion is: Why concludes that $\mu(E)$ converges absolutely?

Thank you all.

Comment: It would help if we knew what Theorem 3.56 was.

Comment: Theorem 3.56: If $\sum a_n$ is a series of complex numbers which converges absolutely then every rearragement of $\sum a_n$ converges, and they all converge to the same sum.

Answer (score 0):

Theore 3.56 that you've cited seems to prove another direction. Perhaps, here we rather shall use [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318799/riemann-rearrangement-theorem). Notice that in your case, not only every rearrangement converges, they all do converge to the same limit $\mu(E)$. If the series were not absolutely convergent, then there would exist two rearrangements with different limits.