# Determine convergence or divergence $-1+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4^3}+\frac{1}{5^3}-\frac{1}{3}+...$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Determine convergence or divergence $-1+\dfrac{1}{2^3}+\dfrac{1}{3^3}-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4^3}+\dfrac{1}{5^3}-\dfrac{1}{3}+...$

This was a question on my undergrad Real Analysis exam. Would it be enough to state divergence given that the negative terms of the harmonic series are present?

Comment: I would say you need to prove that the series of the positive terms converge.

Comment: It appears that the terms being subtracted are always less than the subsequent terms being added. So I believe that shows divergence. But how do I formalize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that if two series are convergent, then their series-sum converges, too.

Consider the infinite series:

$$0 - \frac{1}{2^3} -  \frac{1}{3^3} + 0 - \frac{1}{4^3} - \frac{1}{5^3} + 0 - \cdots $$

This series converges as the zeroes do not affect the limit of its partial sums, and so we essentially have here $-\sum_{n>1} 1/n^3$, which converges (maybe you have seen this called a $p$-series with $p > 2$).

Suppose your original series converged as well, and we will find a contradiction: For if your series converged, we could add it with the convergent series above to get a convergent series:

$$-1 + 0 + 0 - 1/2 + 0 + 0 - 1/3 + \cdots$$

But this last series *diverges*: It is the (negation of the) harmonic series with some zeroes interspersed. And so our supposition that your series is convergent was incorrect; it diverges.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite. The negative part is the harmonic series, which diverges. The positive part is convergent, and these two facts together imply the divergence to $-\infty$ of the original series. This isn't hard to show and you should give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

If you check for this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem), you will understand why rearrange the series will yields very different result in terms of convergence. And actually, if the series is conditionally converge, you could re-arrange the series to get what ever value on $\mathbb R$.

I also want to point to this question on math.SE for [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318799/riemann-rearrangement-theorem), which has extended discussion on this topic over $\mathbb R^n$.